# Regex fixed amount of number with fixed amount of spaces

Tags: regex

Sup gang.
I am looking for a solution to write a regex that would match a string with 11 digits and one space in between those numbers.
For example this:
12345678901 - should match (no spaces are ok) 
1234567890 1 - should match 
123456 78901 - should match 
12345 6789 12 - should not match since there are 2 spaces

The only solution I could think of playing with regex101 was to check each scenario separately, which is stupid... 
 like (\d{1}\s{1}\d{10})|(\d{2}\s\d{9})...

**Edit:**
Space is optional
I need to get 11 numbers in total

Any better way of achieving the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `/^(?=.{12}$)\d+ \d+$/`. Is the space required or is it optional? Can it be at the start/end?

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/9agi1J/1)?